# Nginx: example.com works; example.com/folder gets 403 Forbidden

Tags: permissions, nginx, http-status-code-403

I just set up Nginx for the first time, having liked what I read about its advantages over Apache.

My problem is this: I start up Nginx on my Linux Mint (12, 32-bit) box.  `index.html` is located at

```
/usr/share/nginx/www
```

I also have a folder located at

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/store
```

which contains some ISO files, but no html files (so there is not even an index.html).  In Apache, this would result in a folder directory, and I'm hoping to get something similar from Nginx -- I thought that was a basic functionality feature.

It is worth noting that

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/store
```

is a mounting point that I use for a Samba share.

**Here's the problem:**

I go to access my Linux box from my other machine.  By going to `www.example.com`, I am greeted with the standard "Welcome to nginx" message.  When I go to `www.example.com/store`, I get a "403 Forbidden" error instead of a directory listing of the files in `/store`.

I've read lots about permissions being the cause of 403 errors, but I don't see how I could've missed anything.  In mild desperation, I edited nginx.conf to say

```
user root;
```

so nginx is running as root, even though I know that's not the best idea (I just wanted to see if it was a permissions issue).  Both `usr/share/nginx/www` and `usr/share/nginx/www/store` (as well as the ISO files contained therein) have permissions `drwxr-xr-x` and are owned by `root root`.  The Samba server works just fine, and I have full access to `/store` from my other computer, but I can't get at it from a browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the autoindex configuration to 'on' in the nginx server configuration. Ex:

```
location  /  {
  autoindex  on;
}
```

By default the value is OFF

Ref: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAutoindexModule